# Memory regarding broadcast variables in spark

Tags: apache-spark

Assuming I have a cluster with two worker nodes and from these two workers, I have 10 executors. How much memory will be used up in my cluster if I choose to broadcast a 1gb Map?

Will it be 1gb per worker so 2gb in total? Or will it be 1gb per executor so 10gb in total?

Apologies for the simple question, but for me, a number of articles written about broadcast variables aren’t 100% clear on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executers are the entities that perform the actual work. Each executor is its own JVM process with allotted memory.

(As described here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html)

The broadcast is materialized at the executer level so in the above example- 10GB.